Label defined in my preambule are not listed in \ref Overleaf
For my maths studies, I use a way to create theorems boxes, definitions etc...
    %Theorem
\newcounter{theo}[part] \setcounter{theo}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetheo}{\arabic{part}.\arabic{theo}}
\newenvironment{theoreme}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{theo}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rounded corners,fill=red!60]
{\strut Theorema~\thetheo};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rounded corners,fill=red!60]
{\strut Theorema~\thetheo:~#1};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=red!60,%
linewidth=2pt,topline=true,%
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax
}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
\label{#2}}{\end{mdframed}}

Most of it is just used to create a box etc... but the important part is
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
\label{#2}}{\end{mdframed}}

where I define a label for the Theorem.
While I can use /ref{labelname} and it works very well, the name of the created labels does not appear in the list of suggested labels when I write \ref{...}.
It only shows the labels I have created by hand in the file.
Here's an example where I can't find the "PDE" label in the list of labels :

Thanks in advance

The Overleaf suggestion list is very simple, it contains only (literal) things found in \label{} statements in the source code, it does not do any processing to resolve constructed labels like this. You can see that #2 is also in the list, as \label{#2} occurs literally in the source of the definition environment. So in this case you have to remember or look up the label name yourself.

Note that framed theorems are a lot easier to do with tcolorbox than with mdframed, the former can even just wrap itself around and existing theorem env. That way the normal \label inside the theorem still works and the suggestions still works.

Thanks a lot it answers perfectly my question
